# XML::Twig perl SVG filter with minimum parsing possible? start_tag_handler?

Tags: perl, parsing, svg

The filter code snippet below does something very simple.
If a top level SVG group is tagged with a label contained in a matchlist, its visibility is enforced (< g style="display:) and the group, as well as non grouped code, is copied *as is* to standard output (flush). Else, the group is removed from the stream (purge).
The question is this:
As I understand it, each whole group (which may be large) is parsed in turn and stored in memory, which is not necessary as only the start tag is examined and modified. What would be the code modifications to stop reading the file after the start tag and then to fly down to the matching < /g> end tag, copying the traversed code or not, without parsing anything than the nesting of tags?
I read that start_tag_handler is supposed to do that, but I couldn't manage to use flush or purge correctly.
As a bonus, return if $g->parent->gi eq "g"; which may be incorrect would no longer be necessary as interior groups would no longer be handled (before the exterior group).
Reports of any error would of course be appreciated: trifle: $indent seems to do nothing; anything wrong?
Full code and examples to play with @ http://www.papou.byethost9.com/notes/svg-sieve/
svg-sieve -d all  to test the inline example with debug.
svg-sieve -d ma  -l Ixelles,language=ru,names=ru  Brussels-municipalities.svg > Brussels-Ixelles-ru.svg
-d mi to discover the layers.

< thanks times=1000 />

André.

```
my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_roots => { 'g' => \&g },
       twig_print_outside_roots => 1, pretty_print => "$indent",);

sub g { my ($t, $g) = @_; 
  return if $g->parent->gi eq "g";
  my $label=$g->att("inkscape:label");
  $label or $label=$g->att("id");
  if ( $label ~~ @matchlist | $label =~ /^BASE-/) {
    my $style=$g->att("style");
    $style =~ s/display:[^;]*(;?)/display:inline\1/;
    $g->set_att( style => "$style");
    $g-> flush;
  } else {
    $g-> purge;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $indent won't do anything if, as a Perl var, it is not set to one of the property values Twig expects ('nice', 'indented' etc.)

Secondly, I'm not quite sure what you're aiming at. It seems like your memory concerns lie solely with the  elements you don't want. If so, you may not need to use tag_handlers.

You can explicitly match the  elements you want by joining your @matching on "|" in the Xpath of a user-defined handler. I would also flush $twig just after your parse line.

You also don't need this `#return if $g->parent->gi eq "g";` if your XPath to `<g>` is absolute, e.g. `'/root/parent/g'`.

```
my $twig_handlers = {
      'g[string(label) =~ /['.join('|',@matchlist).']/]' => sub { g_handler($_) },
   };

my $twig = new XML::Twig( 
      twig_roots => { 'g' => 1 },
      twig_handlers => $twig_handlers,
      twig_print_outside_roots => 1, pretty_print => $indent,);

sub g_handler { 
   my $g = shift;
   my $label=$g->att("label");
   $label or $label=$g->att("id");
   if ( $label ~~ @matchlist | $label =~ /^BASE-/) {
      my $style=$g->att("style");
      $style =~ s/display:[^;]*(;?)/display:inline$1/;
      $g->set_att( style => "$style");
      $g-> flush;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm presently invited to work on OpenStreetMap for the Philippines Typhoon, that gets priority but I'll try your code and I'll come back. My memory concern is about the selected elements as much as the rejected ones. I've read horror stories about the memory size taken by some XML files and that's why I'd like to use start_tag_handler which uses minimal memory independent on the size of the group element.